# Karger's algorithm does not work for single run and crashes for multiple runs

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, random, graph

I am trying to implement Karger's algorithm for finding mincuts in am undirected graph. The graph I'm using is having 8 edges as shown in the t2 2D VEctor.

For this, I used 2D Vectors and an adjacency list implementation of graphs.

For selecting a random edge, I actually selected a vertex at random, and then another vertex from its edge list at random to select the "random" edge.

However, even though I believe I followed all the steps properly, the algorithm does not seem to give a proper answer for one run, and segfaults on multiple runs...

My code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 201

using namespace std;

typedef  int64_t  int64;

//RNG Stuff
random_device rd;
mt19937_64 rng(rd());
uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(1, 9);

vector< vector<int64> > t(MAX_ELEMENTS);

vector < vector<int>> t2(9);


int mincut = 0;

void printVector(){
    for (auto j : t2) {
        for (auto l : j)
            cout << l << " ";
        cout << endl << "Hahaha " << j.size() << endl;
    }
}


int randomNum() {
    return uni(rng);
}

int KargersAlgorithm(void) {
    int minOfTwo;
    t2  = {{}, {1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,7},

        {2, 1 ,3 ,4},

        {3, 1, 2, 4},

        {4, 1, 2, 3, 5},

        {5, 4, 6 ,7 ,8},

        {6, 5, 7, 8},

        {7, 1 ,5 ,6, 8},

        {8, 5, 6, 7}};

    while (t2.size() > 3) {


        /*
         * Randomly select vertices
         */

       int nodeStart = 0;
        while(nodeStart == 0)
            nodeStart = randomNum() % t2.size();
        int nodeEnd = 0;

        while(nodeEnd == 0)
        nodeEnd = randomNum() % t2[nodeStart].size();

        //Insert all the edges from nodeEnd to nodeStart aka merge the vertices

        t2[nodeStart].insert(t2[nodeStart].end(), t2[nodeEnd].begin(), t2[nodeEnd].end());

        //Node renaming
        for (int i = 1; i < t2[nodeEnd].size(); i++) { //For each vertex in nodeEnd

            int foundEdge = t2[nodeEnd][i]; //Found an edge from nodeEnd to foundEdge,, so need to rename all the nodeEnd to nodeStart in this list

           // cout<< "i: " << i << "  FoundEdge:  " << foundEdge <<  endl;
            replace(t2[foundEdge].begin(), t2[foundEdge].end(), t2[nodeEnd][0],  t2[nodeStart][0]); //Replace all the nodeEnd with t2[nodeStart][0] since that gives the ID number

        }

        //Remove self-loops from nodeStart
        t2[nodeStart].erase(std::remove(t2[nodeStart].begin() + 1, t2[nodeStart].end(), t2[nodeStart][0]),
                            t2[nodeStart].end());

        //Kill nodeEnd :(
        t2.erase(t2.begin() + nodeEnd);

    }
    //printVector();


     return  min(t[1].size(), t[2].size());
}

int main(){
    int min = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        t2.clear();
        int x = KargersAlgorithm();
        if(x < min)min = x;
    }
    cout << min;
return 0;
}
```

A single run of the algorithm gives the following as the final array (just removing the repeated calls to the KargersAlgorithm() function):

```
4 2 3 5 2 3 7
5 4 6 7 8 7 4 6 8 8 6
```

Since the first element signifies the vertex numbers, apparently vertices 4 and 5 are left in the end.

So well, here are my doubts:

1. Is there a better way to select the vertices randomly in this implementation? Right now, since t[0] has nothing since I'm indexing from 1 to 8, any access to t[0] will crash the program.
2. Is the output I am getting correct? I kinda feel it should be something like

   4 5 5 5 5 5

   5 4 4 4 4 4

But it might be that I don't understand properly...

3. What is the actual mincut value I'm supposed to get? And how can I deduce it from the output? Right now I'm thinking is the minimum of the two sizes but it seems very wrong...
4. The program crashes whenever I try to run it several times. Here is the ideone link for the same code:

http://ideone.com/LsGhiO

I understand that my understanding might be incomplete, but so far, everywhere else I've seen on the web, either I cannot understand the code or the places do not use the implementation I did.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT1: As per suggestions from samgak and Patryk Obara. I added a clear() at the beginning of each function call, as well as expanded the t2 array size declration to 9 (even though that may not matter much), but even then it crashes. According to CLion, at the 29th iteration, it crashes at the line replace() (line 96 in the code) due to a junk negative value in foundEdge, even though the addresses seem legit. So I'm still puzzled... Thanks in advance!

Comment: My suggestion would be to run this through debugger, see where it crashes, and go from there. First crash is line, where you are filling `t2` (you put 9 elements into a vector of size 8). Second crash happens in line, where you "merge the vertices". Unfortunately I don't have time to read into your implementation and follow up at the moment.

Comment: Call clear() on your vectors at the start of your KargersAlgorithm function

Comment: I added both of your suggestions, as well as checked with a debugger where it's crashing and when. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Some another comment: concatenating two vectors is not the best way of merging two vertices (you want to remove duplicates after all, which seems to be missing from you algorithm) - you might want to use `std::set<int>` for adjacency list - merging two sets will remove duplicates automatically.

Comment: Hmm, I see. However, won't merging them while removing duplicates remove any parallel edges that were present?